How to add multiple logos to a quarto book on the cover page of the book rendered docx
I am creating a quarto book for a report co-authored by 4 NGOs. I need to add the 4 logos on the cover page of the rendered Word document. Please, I need your help to achieve this by adding a list of the logo URLs horizontally in the _quarto.yml file using R.
I have tried:
book: cover-image: cover.png
But it doesn't work with Word documents i.e. docx

According to the docs the cover-image option is only supported by HTML and ePub. Perhaps you can use a custom reference docx where you place the logos in the header for the first page only?

Ok. I will try it out

Note that a cover page is different from the first page. Perhaps you should edit the question so it's clear.
